# LUIS Pre-Built Domains missing Utilities

Tags: azure-language-understanding

The documentation for LIUS pre-built domains says there is a domain called "Utilities"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-domains#list-of-prebuilt-domains

However, when searching from the "Add pre-built domain entity" button on the luis.ai web interface this domain cannot be found:
[image: pre-buit domain not found]

Answer (score 0):

I realize I was looking in the wrong place. The pre-built domain "Utilities" only has intents, no entities, and I was trying to add a pre-built entity.

You can find the utilities domain by going to Intents --> Add prebuilt intent

Comment: I'm not sure that you are speacking about domains, I found that this function is visible on an app with culture "en-us" and not visible if the culture is set as "it-it"!